# NextJs :pid routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Does anybody know what is the  exportPathMap: (next.config.js) for NextJS of a path that has a :pid?

My expotPathMap

```
  exportPathMap: async (defaultPathMap) => {
  return {
  '/': { page: '/', query: {} },
  '/login': { page: '/login', query: { verifySuccess: null } },
  '/signup': { page: '/signup', query: {} },
  '/search': { page: '/search', query: { s: '', category: '' } },
  '/messages': { page: '/messages', query: { t: '' } },
  '/messages/:pid': { page: '/messages/:pid', query: { t: '' } },
```

Issue is that I was tasked to create a page that would look like
/messages/925255252 
instead of a page that uses a query param like /message?id=9252552252&t=foo

Now when building & exporting I am getting this error

```
Cannot find module for page: /messages/:pid
```

The files.

> pages > messages > index.js (/messages), [pid].js (messages/:id)

PS.
Not using SSR, rendering is client sided!

PPS.
All is fine on localhost, needs to work in production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is not possible, from the spectrum [chat](https://spectrum.chat/next-js/general/dynamic-parameters-in-exportpathmap~f94c9cca-4aaa-49b7-9885-85bb35649a7a) of next.js :

> You have to return a mapping of every possible route, dynamic matching
>   wouldn't have any effect even if we did support it, how would you know
>   what /show/:id is going to be when exporting? We have to know exactly
>   what is going to be exported at export time

So you have to generate all possibile pages (in your case you need all possible messages ids), [example](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/master/examples/with-static-export/next.config.js) fetching your database.
Or switch to SSR and handle your requests server side.